# Problem using DIVs and floating SPANs

Tags: html, css

currently I have a very simple form with the following:

```
<div class="datepicker">
   <p>
      From: 
      <span class="spanMonth">
         <div id="div_dateFromReports_month">
            <select></select>
         </div>
      </span>
      <span class="spanDay">
         <div id="div_dateFromReports_day">
            <select></select>
         </div>
      </span>
      <span class="spanYear">
         <div id="div_dateFromReports_year">
            <select></select>
         </div>
      </span>
   </p>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Now, the classes on every span only contain a "float: left", which as a result makes them float and place the "From" word to the right, which is of course unintended, is there any way to put the "From" word to it's intended position without wrapping it?

Note: the  tags were cut to avoid filling the question with unnecessary data.

It looks like this:

```
   _______   ________   ________
  |_______| |________| |________| From:
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
          _______   ________   ________
 From:   |_______| |________| |________|
```

NOTE:
As I commented below, yes, I know, the broken HTML, sadly this is a part of a page which is already hacked with jQuery and lots of broken view helpers (Zend), right now all I'm trying is to fix this as I really can't modify the structure, the SELECTs come from php, the spans containing the DIVs come from a Zend view helper and so on. As of right now, there's not much I can do, you know how software companies are asking for things right away...hate to hack HTML, but right now it can't be helped. Thank you for all your input :)

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? A select inside a div inside a span inside a p?

Comment: Just to clarify as I've seen a lot of comments about it, I'll add it to the question too as a special note, the main problem here is...yes, I know, the broken HTML, sadly this is a part of a page which is already hacked with jQuery and lots of broken view helpers (Zend), right now all I'm trying is to fix this as I really can't modify the structure, the SELECTs come from php, the spans containing the DIVs come from a Zend view helper and so on.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. It certainly seems excessive. Hopefully you can get it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a7uwd/)** (Only tested in FireFox 3.6.x)

Remove the `float: left;` and use this CSS:

```
.datepicker span div { display: inline; }
```

---

**Alternate solution:** (assuming you can edit the HTML)

```
<div class="datepicker">
      From:
      <select></select>
      <select></select>
      <select></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Making a `div` `display:inline` is nonsensical to me. Instead of hacking the CSS to make broken HTML work, you should instead enforce creating semantic HTML that validates so you don't have to do things like making a div 'inline.'

Comment: @Moses: The OP may not have access to the HTML output, so my answer focuses on a CSS-only solution. Also, I've added an alternate solution that refactors the HTML to achieve the same result. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you imagined my problem of not being able to change something that broken, but this little "hack" really works, thank you very much. EDIT: I've seen your other comment, and as I imagined, you suspected my "not being able" to modify the html output :)

Comment: @Ozmah: I find that the quick, easy fixes are often the only viable ones. (Anecdotal: At my work, I've inherited a website that was developed about 12 years ago, and much of it **cannot** be refactored with cleaner code without breaking the entire thing.)

Comment: Yes, I'm in a very similar situation right now, I really tried changing the entire view helpers to clean the code, but it's so broken, I can't change a single thing without having to rewrite the entire class.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you have two options.

1. Option 1:  Put the "From" text in a
   span that is floated left.
2. Option 2:
   Remove float left from the spans. 
   (spans are inline elements so they
   won't self clear and thus shouldn't
   need a float applied to them)

EDIT:  Ack I see why you have the spans floated.  You have divs inside your spans which is not really correct.  What I would do to clean things up is remove the spans around the divs, float the divs left, add a div around the "From" text and float that left.

Comment: How about just remove the divs AND spans. Neither are helping in this case. Apply both the class and the ID to the select element, which is `inline-block` by default, and let the browsers do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is make the HTML valid: a `span` can't contain a `div`. Once the HTML is valid, start working on the style from there. As it stands, I can't even reproduce the problem in Safari 5.